# What does it mean to say that a neural network was "fine-tuned end-to-end"?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, terminology, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I was reading this article (Faster R-CNN: Towards Real-Time Object Detection with Regional Proposal Network) and in yellow line:

[image]

What is the meaning of *fine-tuned end-to-end*?

Comment: Related: [Fine Tuning vs Joint Training vs Feature Extraction](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/255364/12359) + [What does end to end mean in deep learning methods?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/224118/12359)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It's not actual duplicate since I mean both end to end and fine tune terms

Comment: the combination of both terms doesn't change the meaning of each term taken individually.

Comment: @in duplicate question there is no define for fine-tuned

Comment: "You train a model on a dataset, use it for training on another dataset. This is fine tuning. [..] in the fine-tuning strategy all weights are changed when training on the new task"

Comment: @I was looking for this answer , that user.. posted below , and it's not in duplicate question , that's why I said it's not duplicate

Comment: I see. Unfortunately Stack Exchange doesn't allow a user to mark a question as a duplicate of two other questions: [Question A is a duplicate of question B + question C: what to do?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/4565/12359)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the sentence is: They started with a network (ImageNet) that had been trained on some other data set. They then trained this network on a new task ('region proposal') by feeding it examples from a new data set and adjusting the parameters to minimize the new loss function (i.e. using end-to-end training). Some more information about the term 'end-to-end training' can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224118/what-does-end-to-end-mean-in-deep-learning-methods) and [here](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-for-a-neural-network-to-be-trained-end-to-end).